# Is there a way to search for a string that searches all characters including "<" characters?

Tags: innerhtml

Ill try to be specific as I can.  I tried using ..text.content and ..innerhtml and both seem to be missing the "<" character when searching.  When searching this total string below it does not see it.

This is what i am searching for on a specific html page.

'''

```
    '231-8&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&lt;p class=\&quot;stock out-of-stock'
```

'''
And this is my code...

```
    'if ('
    'document.documentElement.textContent.search('231-8&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&lt;p class=\&quot;stock out-of-stock') != -1)'
    '{'
    'alert("FOUND!");'
    '} else {'
    'alert("NOT FOUND!");'
    '}'
```

'''
I can search the first part of the string all the way up to the "&lt" part and it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I figured it out this was my solution 231-8&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\\\\&quot;stock out-of-stock

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution I figured it out...

```
    '231-8&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\\\\&quot;stock out-of-stock
```